# IMG keeps resizing when trying to zoom it using :HOVER within the card

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to "Code" a cards still in early process of learning to code...i cant figure how to keep IMG from resizing over the headder when trying to zoom it in on hover i've been googling for hours and cant get it right...
now i know there is going to be a LOT of useless code but i still cant recognize a good code so please dont roast me on that :/

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: #5c6370;

}
.cards{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;

}

.card{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 510px;
    width: 380px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2rem 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.671);
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in;
    margin: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    
}
.card:hover{
    transform: scale(1.07); 
}

.card img { 
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    transition: transform .4s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.card-header h1{
    margin: 15px;
}

.card-bttns button{
    margin: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    padding: 10px 17px;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #5c637000;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}

.card-bttns button:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cards</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="cards-top">
        <div class="cards">
            <div class="card">
                <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519681393784-d120267933ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=80', alt='Snowy Mountains'>
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h1>Pretty Mountain</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="card-info"><p>Very Much Snowy i like snow <br>i like to throw snowballs wow its cool <br>
                    do zou like to throw snowballs? Cause i Do!</p></div>
                <div class="card-bttns">
                    <button type="submit">Follow</button>
                    <button type="submit">Contact</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, adding *overflow: hidden* to the photo doesn't make sense. You need to add this to the div which will contain the photo. Then the image will increase but will not go beyond the div - of course you have to give the constant height.

Try this code:

1. I added new div to image.
2. Added css styles to class card-img-hld

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: #5c6370;

}
.cards{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;

}

.card{
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 510px;
    width: 380px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 2rem 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.671);
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in;
    margin: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    
}
.card:hover{
    transform: scale(1.07); 
}

.card img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
    transition: transform .4s;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.card-header h1{
    margin: 15px;
}

.card-img-hld {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 250px;
}

.card-bttns button{
    margin: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    padding: 10px 17px;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #5c637000;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}

.card-bttns button:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cards</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="cards-top">
        <div class="cards">
            <div class="card">
               <div class="card-img-hld">
                <img src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519681393784-d120267933ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=80', alt='Snowy Mountains'>  
              </div>
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h1>Pretty Mountain</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="card-info"><p>Very Much Snowy i like snow <br>i like to throw snowballs wow its cool <br>
                    do zou like to throw snowballs? Cause i Do!</p></div>
                <div class="card-bttns">
                    <button type="submit">Follow</button>
                    <button type="submit">Contact</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ooooo i get what you mean, i get the picture now!! Thank you very much!